# Deciding a circle rotation reachability problem?

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, computer-science, computability, decidability

Let $x \in [0,1]$ be an *irrational algebraic number*, and $y \in [0,1]$ algebraic.  Does there exist an effective procedure for determining whether there exists some integer $k \geq 1$ such that
$$
kx \equiv y \mod 1?
$$
This can be thought of a question about circle rotations from dynamics: marking a point at $0$, if we rotate the circle by an angle that is an irrational algebraic number, does there exist some iteration of the rotation where the marked point equals some target value in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?

For example, when $x = \sqrt{2}/4$, and $y = \sqrt{2}/2$, we can find that there exists a $k=2$ solving the problem.  But it is unclear if this is the case in general.

Comment: A Turing machine can't represent an irrational number. Is the Turing machine representing $x$ as its minimal polynomial with bounds to distinguish which root, or something? Or do you imagine an extended machine which can store and perform certain operations on real numbers?

Comment: The more severe problem is $y$, which as the question is currently written could be any real number in $[0,1]$ and thus can’t be represented by a Turing machine at all (since there are more real numbers than the countable states of a Turing machine).

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for pointing out these issues, I have changed the question so that $y$ is algebraic.  Moreover it seems that wording this question in terms of Turing machines is misleading for as you point out the input must be finite.  Thus what I am seeking is some effective procedure to solve the problem.  Some irrational algebraic numbers can be represented symbolically, so an example where the problem is decidable is when $x=\sqrt{2}/2$ and $y=\sqrt{2}/4$ for instance, then $k=2$.

Comment: @joriki see the above comment as well

Comment: @user918212: Not just some irrational algebraic numbers can be represented symbolically – as aschepler had suggested, algebraic numbers can be represented by their minimal polynomials, together with bounds that distinguish the roots. Anyway, please clarify the question itself; it shouldn’t rely on the comments for clarity.

Comment: @joriki I have edited the question.

Comment: If $x=\sqrt2/2$, and $y=\sqrt2/4$, and $k=2$, then $kx=\sqrt2$, and $\sqrt2\equiv\sqrt2/4\bmod1$ is false. Maybe you swapped $x$ and $y$? Anyway, if $x$ is irrational, whether algebraic or not, there is clearly no integer $k$ such that $kx\equiv0\bmod1$.

Comment: A necessary condition is that $x$ and $y$ generate the same extension of the rationals. I don't know whether there is an efficient way to determine this. Also, it's not sufficient, just necessary.

Comment: Another necessary condition: if $x$ is an algebraic irrational, then there is a smallest positive integer $d$ such that $dx$ is an algebraic integer. Then a necessary condition is that $dy$ also be an algebraic integer.

Comment: There's still value in discussing this in terms of a Turing machine or an extension of a Turing machine or something similar if slightly less formal. "Is there an effective procedure" is too vague unless we know what data we start with and what steps are and aren't valid in an algorithm.

Comment: I note that OP has corrected the values of $x$ and $y$ in the example. I don't know why OP is still asking about $kx\equiv0\bmod1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for your comments, I have edited the question.

Comment: I think this may be a hard problem. I don't even see how to tell whether real algebraic irrationals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ generate the same extension of the rationals.

Comment: Question now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467810/is-it-decidable-whether-two-real-algebraic-irrationals-generate-the-same-extensi

Comment: Yes thanks @GerryMyerson